# How to handle an xml with an empty tag in android?? Like this <pager/>

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

So i have a file in my assests folder that I am reading in. 
I am reading it in with no errors. But here is an example of a record or item in the xml file. (I took out the real values and put fake data in)

```
  <record>
    <group> MYGROU </group>
    <name> Person </name>
    <title> (MG1217) LEADER </title>
    <businessphone> 111-111-1111 </businessphone>
    <pager/>
    <email> email.org </email>
    <managername> BOSS </managername>
    <managerbusinessphone> 1919191919 </managerbusinessphone>
    <managerpager/>
    <manageremail> email.org </manageremail>
</record>
```

Anyways, I created an object and read in everything correctly except for the cases like Pager and managerpager. Here is what is read in or I think is read in as the value from the xml.

```
V/value of pager after set Text﹕ [ 02-17 12:16:25.476 17462:17462 D/Activity ]
performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
```

Ideally what I want to do is to set the value of Pager to N/A since there is no value in the xml for it. But I am not sure how to go about this since I am not really pulling a value whenever I parse it. I tried to take the substring of that string I am printing out, but I cant even take the substring of it.

Here is how I am taking the subsring and what it prints out

Substring and how i tried to set the value to N/A in a Textview I created (mOnCallPager).

```
 Log.v("substring value of pager ", item.getMpager().substring(0,5));

  if(item.getMpager().substring(0,2).equals(" ["))
    {
        mOnCallPager.setText("N/A");
    }
    else
        mOnCallPager.setText(item.getMpager());
```

Value it prints out

```
  02-17 12:29:43.516  22838-22838/com.example.jaimejahuey.novanthealthmobile V/substring value of pager﹕ [ 02-17 12:29:43.516 22838:22838 D/Activity ]
performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
```

Any help would be helpful. 
Thanks

Heres my parsing of the xml.

```
                      switch (evenType)
                {
                    //make a new contact whenever the startag is record
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("record"))
                        {
                            contact = new OnCallContact();
                        }
                        break;


                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = parser.getText();
                        break;



                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if(tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("record"))
                        {
                            contacts.add(contact);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("group"))
                        {
                            contact.setMgroup(text);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
                        {
                            contact.setMname(text);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                        {
                            contact.setMtitle(text);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("businessphone"))
                        {
                            contact.setMbusinessPhone(text);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("pager"))
                        {
                             contact.setMpager(text);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("email"))
                        {
                            contact.setMemail(text);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("managername"))
                        {
                            contact.setmManagerName(text);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("managerbusinessphone"))
                        {
                            contact.setmManagerBusinessPhone(text);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("managerpager"))
                        {
                            contact.setmManagerPager(text);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("manageremail"))
                        {
                            contact.setmManagerEmail(text);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                evenType = parser.next();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incase someone ever has this issue, it is whitespace that the parser will grab. Mine was 9 in length. So it was more then just a single whitespace. Anyways, if you don't get null when grabbing the value, then you are most likely grabbing whitespace like i was. (Trim whenever reading in the text, so that way the length of the empty tags is 0 and do whatever you need to do with the empty tags)